# How redirect program's stdout and stderr to one file, and the same stderr to another file?

Tags: bash, redirect, tee

I want to have a log file `merged.log` which stores the full program output (stdout and stderr) so I can see error logs alongside non-error logs, but also have a file `error.log` only for error lines so I can quickly view problems in the program. I have tried using `tee` but I can't figure out how to perform this particular type of redirection.

For example, if I have the following javascript program

```
// outputter.js
console.log('this is stdout');
console.error('this is stderr');
```

then the two log files should be

```
# merged.log
this is stdout
this is stderr
```

and

```
# error.log
this is stderr
```

Answer (score 2):

In BASH this works for me:

```
((./a.out 2>&1 1>&3 | tee error.log) 3>&1 1>&2) > merged.log 2>&1
```

There is a good explanation at [this page.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)

Comment: Will this preserve the original order of the messages on `stderr` and `stdout`? For example if you replace `./a.out` with `(ls . nonexistent; ls . nonexistent)`, that should have interleaving normal and error outputs. Your answer may be acceptable if you mention the limitation about ordering.

Comment: @janos I ran your suggested command, and it does correctly interleave stdout and stderr outputs

Comment: @roger Your command works as expected, but after some fiddling I found that if I remove the `1>&2` right before the last parenthesis, I still get the expected output in the two log files. Why is it necessary to to redirect fd 1 to 2?